# deleting elements created by jquery in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build my first plugin using jquery.

So far successful, but I'm stuck in deleting the notifications.

I was able to delete the notification on a click event.

```
Notification.prototype.destroy = function(element) {
    var self = this;

    element.closest('.notification-container').remove();
};
```

And I call that function inside `init` method.

```
Notification.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.$el.on('click', function() {
        self.build();
    });

    self.$body.on('click', '.close', function() {
        self.destroy(this);
    })
};
```

Now I wanted to give a auto close option to the user, and I thought of using the `setTimeout` function, but as I've created the function passing the parameter as current element, I'm unable to get it.

Here's the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXONok?editors=0010).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several problems there:

1. The `setTimeout` function must be called upon display (and not upon build), otherwise it can be called even before you display the notification (hence your notification will not be automatically removed).
2. When you call the `setTimeout` in order to destroy the notification - you need to pass the container of the notification you just created, so the destroy function will be able to find the relevant element to remove (when you use the `click` option - you pass the `X` element, so it's easy to find the closest container, but when you use the `setTimeout` you must pass the container element himself).

I think all of the changes I made are in the `build` function, here it is:

```
Notification.prototype.build = function() {
    var self = this;

    var closeHTML = self.options.autoClose ? '' : '';

    if (self.options.type == 'thumb') {
        var $notificationHTML = $('<div class="notification-container">' +
                                    '<i class="close">x</i>' + 
                                    '<div class="notification">' +
                                        '<div class="thumb-container">' +
                                            '<img src="' + self.options.src + '">' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<p>' + self.options.text + '</p>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>');
    } else {
        var $notificationHTML = $('<div class="notification-container">' +
                                '<i class="close">x</i>' + 
                                '<div class="notification ' + self.options.style + '">' +
                                    '<p>' + self.options.text + '</p>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>');

    }
    self.$body.prepend($notificationHTML);
    if(self.options.autoClose) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.destroy($notificationHTML);
        }, 5000)
    } else {
        self.$body.on('click', '.close', function() {
            self.destroy(this);
        })
    }
};
```

And a working codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKgPgB?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I think if I trigger two notification at once, the gap is not 10 seconds for the second notification to go off. Will you be able to help me on that? +1 as well for your help :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can you please try to explain?

Comment: Basically, if I hit the button twice, the first notification triggered should go off in 5 seconds. And the second notification should have a 5 secs delay after the first one goes off. Can that be done?

Comment: You will need to have a queue for that and make sure once the function is finished you will need to call back the queue to see if there is a new function in the queue that should be executed. Not sure you have something like that built in in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try to dig into it.

Comment: One small information, you've wrapped the HTML inside jQuery in the self.options.type. Can you pls tell what is the reason, because when I was trying it without wrapping inside jQuery. It wasn't working.

Comment: Sure, your `destroy` function needs a `jQuery` object because it uses `element.closest`. If you will not wrap that html block with jQuery - the `self.$body.prepend` will work (because it can take both `string` and `jQuery`), but your `destroy` function will not work (because there is no such thing `string.closest`).

Comment: Hmmm.. Thank you very much :)